# How to define Jquery script for layout page and content page

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I created layout page and content page.

**scripts from layout**

```
<!-- Jquery Core Js -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**scripts from content page**

```
<!-- Jquery Core Js -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
<script src="~/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Jquery DataTable Plugin Js -->
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/export/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Js -->
<script src="~/js/admin.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/pages/tables/jquery-datatable.js"></script>
```

I used jquery twice in layout and content page so I got an error. But when I removed jquery from layout then content page worked fine but layout didn't worked correctly and vice-versa

So my question is how should I used jquery so that it will worked for layout and content both....?

Comment: you can use jquery only one time in a page try using at your header file which is called at every place in your layout and content sections.

Comment: Thanks ! It works for me....but the jquery effects overrides each other in content page...i.e. when I tried to collapse any panel then it collapsed but suddenly collapse out

Comment: you have to check the code for that if its getting collapsed out everytime and check if you have used  e.preventDefault() function to allow changes to stay at page or not.